# Failed to lookup view in directory with Express Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm following the base app layout you get from Express Generator and attempting to configure it for Handlebars.

Snippet:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

All is well until I try and change the extension for Handlebars to `.hbs` as follows:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
```

(and rename the files of course).

That results in:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

I've looked in `function ExpressHandlebars(config)` in express-handlebars.js source and it does attempt to set extname apppropriately.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Somewhat counter-intuitively, setting the extension name is not enough.

The required setup is:

```
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: For anyone else that didn't see it at first: The engine name has to be the same as the file extension. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @musicin3d it certainly feels like a bug in Express.

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/e5ec966b2f068e935ea1b33374fac133dd06cdc8/lib/application.js#L262

Comment: So it's by design but it seems counter-intuitive, although the fault may lie with express-handlebars. Essentially, as an end user, we end up setting the extension twice.

Answer (score 2):

Creating error.hbs file in views directory solved my issue.

```
 var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

    // view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try that solution:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// Define paths for Exrpress config
const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/views');
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/partials');

// Setup handlebars engine and veiws location
app.set('views', viewsPath);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath);

// Setup static directory to serve
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));
```